# Android: extracting website using BufferedReader: Information extracted are outdated

Tags: android, url, caching, bufferedreader

I am reading html source code of a public website using the following code:

### Code:

```
@Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
         {
            try 
            {
                URL url = new URL(""+URL);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String inputLine;
                PageCode = "";
                OriginalPageCode = "";
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    PageCode += inputLine;
                }                   
                OriginalPageCode = PageCode;
                try
                {
                    extract_website_and_save(); // extracting data from PageCode
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {

                }

                in.close();
            }
```

### Background:

The above code sometimes can fetch the most updated website properly. But occasionally it linked to an outdated version of the website and hence unable to obtain the most updated information for the website.

I am curious why the above will occur, does it related to extracting from cache instead of the real updated website??

I therefore used Chrome to browse the same link, and discovered that Chrome also fetched the outdated website.

I have tried restarting the device, but the problem continues.

After 30 minutes to an hour, I requested the app to fetch again and it then can extract the most updated information. I at the same time browse the website using Chrome, Chrome can now obtain the most updated website.

### Question:

The above BufferedReader should have no relationship with Chrome? But they follow the same logic and hence extracting from cache instead of from the most updated website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect the end point is being cached by URL

Try something like this

```
    urlSrt = urlSrt + "?x=" + new Random().nextInt(100000); 

    // If your URL already is passing parameters i.e. example.com?x=1&p=pass - then modify 
    // the urlSrt line to to use an "&" and not "?" 
    // i.e. urlSrt = urlSrt + "&x=" + new Random().nextInt(100000);

    URL url = new URL(urlSrt);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setUseCaches(false); //This will stop caching!
```

So if you modify your code to something like this.

```
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                con.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have replaced the code with your suggested code and will wait for the update of the website 2 days later (the website updates 3 times every week). Will revert to you that time. thanks a lot! One thing would like to ask is wt is the difference between `con.getInputStream` u suggested and `url.openStream` originally?

Comment: The main reason I used the URLConnection class was that it gives me the flexibility to set the cache flag. Reading around I've found openStream tends to be slower than getInputStram - maybe its down to the caching.

Comment: Hi Zain I have tested 3 times this week, the problem still continues...loading the old one instead of fetching the new data from the website...any more hints?

Comment: OK - so a workaround. The above code will stop caching on the client side (mobile app) there's a possibility your server may be caching also, so try this, urlSrt +"?x=" + new Random(1000000). I'll modify the example above - see how that goes.

Comment: Hi Zain thanks a lot for your continuous help. the website is http://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/index.aspx?lang=en, I have incorporated your suggestion and will try over again for the updates of the website this week (Tue, Thur and Sat) thanks! =)

Comment: Hi Zain, I met problem for the random number suddenly in these few days. Do you have any advice on the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522489/android-url-connection-accessing-to-website